# Roomba + C++ direction sensorPacket reset

Tags: ros, roomba, irobot-create-2-1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So we are currently trying to control a iRobot Create (roomba) with ROS. The problem we are having is that our int16 distance (in the driver) is overflowing and we cant figure out how to reset the distance being read from the roomba.

We have tried to publish a new value to the driver, but it reads the information from teh roomba so it just over rights it..

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42210/roomba-+-c++-direction-sensorpacket-reset/) by [Strider2009](https://answers.ros.org/users/3075/strider2009/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Strider2009](https://answers.ros.org/users/3075/strider2009/) on 2012-08-28**:
The driver was not clearing the distance value, this meant each time it read teh sensor information from the iCreate it would increment this value.
FIX: self.create.clear() - add after line def Twist
located for me at "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/bin/driver.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could try [turtlebot_node](http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_node). It should support the roomba now. You just need to set the parameter `robot_type` to roomba.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0